# Bar and Line Plot for Population Vs Poverty information for top 5 states in USA

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, charts

I want to visualize the data shown in the images below. It needs to be done in `Python`.

[image]

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please modify your Q to make it a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It would be good to show what you tried. Also what kind of plot do you need?